# Email URL from iframe

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form which should send an email with the link of the product the user is currently watching, the problem is that I need to use iframe because the server doesnt accept PHP files, so I have this:

```
 $name = clearValue($_POST["name"]);
        $lastname = clearValue($_POST["lastname"]);
        $company = clearValue($_POST["company"]);
        $phone = clearValue($_POST["phone"]);
        $country = clearValue($_POST["country"]);
        $quantity = clearValue($_POST["quantity"]);
        $mail = ($_POST["mail"]);
        $message = clearValue(nl2br($_POST["message"]));
        $type_quote = clearValue($_POST["type"]);
        $page = currentPageURL();

$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\nFrom: $fromMailStatus \r\nReply-To: $fromMailStatus";
    $body = file_get_contents("resources/mails/mail_newWebLead.htm");
    $body = str_replace("{name}",$name,$body);
    $body = str_replace("{lastname}",$lastname,$body);
    $body = str_replace("{company}",$company,$body);
    $body = str_replace("{phone}",$phone,$body);
    $body = str_replace("{country}",$iPais["nombre"],$body);
    $body = str_replace("{language}",$iLang["nombre"],$body);
    $body = str_replace("{quantity}",$quantity,$body);
    $body = str_replace("{email}",$mail,$body);
    $body = str_replace("{message}",$message,$body);
    $body = str_replace("{link}",$page,$body);
    $body = str_replace("{ip}",$ip_source,$body);

    mail($para,"New Web Lead",$body,$headers);

function currentPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

This works but it returns the page where the iFrame is being called from and I need the original URL, how could I do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand, what exactly is the "original URL"? You have the URL of the page containing the iframe which you get. You also know the URL of the contents of the iframe, since that's your PHP script... so... what are you looking for ?

Comment: I cant get the URL where the iframe is generated.

Comment: You might try $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], but I'm not sure if that will work

Comment: Ah well, the problem (AFAIK) is that this is protected by the browser. Your browser does not allow the contents of the iframe to know the URL of the including page.It _can not_ interact with its parent in any way. This is a security issue

Comment: @Pierre It would show the origin of the parent page. Not the actual parent page.

Comment: However, a simpler way would be to add a token to the URL when calling the iframe. Ie call the iframe as  "www.example.com/somePHPfile.php?I_came_from=1235". Then inside the PHP script you can look up what page it was that it came from by checking some internal table/map.

Comment: @Tularis Actually it will show you the page the iFrame is generated from, I just did a test and it worked

Comment: Hmm, odd... thought it was the other way around; sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] will give you the url of the calling page.

E.G

you have url http://example.com/product/12 with iFrame pointing to http://domain.com/contact.php.

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] will give you http://example.com/product/12

Comment: Would it matter if they are not on the same domain?

Comment: No won't make a difference